# B2C internal error on SignUp

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to setup an Azure AD B2C account in MVC 5 App. But after follow all tutorials in Azure docs I'm getting an strange error, maybe is a wrong configuration or something related, but I follow the guides step by step and still getting de error.

When I ran my `SignUp` Policy, and enter all required claims (currently only EmailAddress, GivenName and SurName), then I click on created and I got an `AuthenticationFailed` notification in my website, with the following exception:

`AADB2C90063: The B2C service has an internal error.
Correlation ID: 859eabf9-9e21-44af-9219-1857e38e9ab2
Timestamp: 2016-06-14 03:37:06Z`

If I create the user in the directory manually via Azure Management Portal (http://manage.windowsazure.com/), I can log in in the app and list all claims, but I can't sign up because I always got above error.

Comment: Could be a typo in the policy name, I've seen the same error and it was a typo somewhere

Comment: I tried ran the policy directly from the azure portal using the 'Run now' button, I got the same error.

Comment: What is the rest of the configuration, which application claims do you send in the signup? just the B2C identity or are you using google,fb,etc?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft, Facebook and Local Account, I got the error no matter what identity provider I choose. I downloaded the reference example from [github] (https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet) and I replaced web.config settings and I got the same error with the quick start example.